# How to confirm data changes in DataGridView GUI (PowerShell)?

Tags: powershell, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

In my case i want to use PS script to build WinForm with some elements including DGV contains of 3 columns (#, Page_Name, shrt). First row need to be template row with default values(1;index;NDX)so i get it from csv-file.
My code:

```
$DataGridView1                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridView1.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,121)
$DataGridView1.Name               = "Page-List"
$DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRowsChanged = $true
$DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = $true
# $DataGridView1.DataBindings
$DataGridView1.width              = 363
$DataGridView1.height             = 150
$DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3
$DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$DataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = '#'
$DataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = "40"
$DataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Page_Name"
$DataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = "205"
$DataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "shrt"
$DataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = "75"
$DataGridView1.ReadOnly = $false
$DataGridView1.EditMode  = "EditOnEnter"
$templateROW = @(Import-Csv -Delimiter ";"  "C:\Users\vkons\OneDrive\Документы\PowerShell\Scripts\test\DGV\index.csv" -Header "#", "Page_Name", "shrt" )
$datatable = ($templateROW + $DataGridView1Rows)
$DataGridView1Data = $datatable

foreach ($Row in $DataGridView1Data){
    $DataGridView1.Rows.Add($Row.'#', $Row.Page_Name, $Row.shrt)
}
```

If user will change Page_Name cells value in first row or will fill Page_Name cell`s in the next row  (or rowS) - cells value in column "#" and column "shrt" in edited row(s) would get values programmly by this part code:

```
$DataGridView1.Add_CellValueChanged({autofill})
Function autofill{

$Numbr = $DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index+1
$DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].value = $Numbr

$Name_Page = $DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].value
$preshrt = $Name_Page.ToString($Value) -ireplace "[aoueyi]" 
$preshrt = $preshrt.ToUpper()
$shrt = $preshrt[0]+$preshrt[1]+$preshrt[2]
$DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].value = $shrt
}
```

My **main target is getting the values of all cells in a column Page_Name** as a variable(or as array). 
 So I tried to add next string to the function above.

```
$Pages = $Row.Page_Name+$DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].value
```

But it returns nothing...(Either $Row.Page_Name)

I can get values of all cells in all rows by

```
$Page_NamesListRows = @($DataGridView1.Rows.Cells.Value)
```

(Unfortunately) it returns varriable, consist of all existing cells, not rows array.
But when i try

```
$Page_Names = $DataGridView1.Rows.Cells[1].Value
```

or

```
$Page_Names = $DataGridView1.Columns[1].Cells.Value
```

to get only Names of the Pages, it returns error "cannot get value of a null-array" (either in case with @(...) for right part)
**Could anybody answer... Is there any way to get values of all existing cells in "Page_Name" Column.
Honestly it doesnt matter would the DGVData automaticly edit by changing cells value event or not.**

***I need to get only column "Page_Name" values.***

In the end I want to apologize for my english language. It has rather poor level. And thank the moderator in advance for corrections my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you will have to get the array of values by looping over the rows in the "Page_Name" column.
The last row in the DataGridView will always be the "New" row to create by the user, so you need to skip that one.

Either by doing this:

```
# -1 to skip the always present empty row at the bottom
$Page_Names = for($row = 0; $row -lt $DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; $row++) {
    $DataGridView1.Rows[$row].Cells.Item("Page_Name").Value
}
```

Or something like:

```
$Page_Names = $DataGridView1.Rows | ForEach-Object {
    $data = $_.Cells.Item("Page_Name").Value
    if ($data) { $data }
}
```

Or:

```
$Page_Names = foreach ($row in $DataGridView1.Rows) {
    $row.Cells.Item("Page_Name").Value
}
$Page_Names = $Page_Names[0..($Page_Names.Count - 2)]
```

<sup>The last alternative is costly, because it needs to recreate the entire array when removing the last item</sup>

<sup>P.S.1 Don't forget to call the `Dispose()` methods on both the $DataGridview1 object and the main form when done with the GUI</sup>

<sup>P.S.2 I don't see a property called `AllowUserToAddRowsChanged` on the DataGridView..</sup>

---

**EDIT**

To hopefully show better what I mean, here's a demo form with a DataGridView control on it.

The initial data comes from a dummy CSV file with this inside:

```
"1";"Page number 1";"PN1"
"2";"Page number 2";"PN2"
"3";"Page number 3";"PN3"
"4";"Page number 4";"PN4"
"5";"Page number 5";"PN5"
```

```
$form            = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ClientSize = New-Object Drawing.Size 580, 505
$form.text       = "20/4/2020 v. 0.1 All Right reserved (c) "
$form.TopMost    = $true

$DataGridView1                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridView1.Location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 20,25
$DataGridView1.Width              = 363
$DataGridView1.Height             = 150
$DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = $true
$DataGridView1.Name               = "Page-List"
$DataGridView1.ColumnCount        = 3
$DataGridView1.Columns[0].Name    = '#'
$DataGridView1.Columns[0].Width   = "40"
$DataGridView1.Columns[1].Name    = 'Page_Name'
$DataGridView1.Columns[1].Width   = "205"
$DataGridView1.Columns[2].Name    = "shrt"
$DataGridView1.Columns[2].Width   = "75"
$DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = $true
$DataGridView1.ReadOnly           = $false

# Populate the DGV with the data from the CSV
$CsvData = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TEMPLATE_ROW.csv' -Delimiter ";" -Header "#", "Page_Name", "shrt"
foreach ($row in $CsvData) {
    [void]$DataGridView1.Rows.Add($row.'#', $row.Page_Name, $row.shrt)
}

# add the DGV to the form
$form.Controls.Add($DataGridView1)

# show the form and capture the result so you can check if the user cancelled or pressed OK
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

# at this point, you can read the data from the DataGridView column of interest
$Page_Names = for($row = 0; $row -lt $DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; $row++) {
    $DataGridView1.Rows[$row].Cells.Item("Page_Name").Value
}

# cleanup memory by destroying the DGV and the from
$DataGridView1.Dispose()
$form.Dispose()
```

In variable `$Page_Names` you will now have the data from the "Page_Name" column in the DataGridView control.

```
# show on screen
$Page_Names
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 
Now Im i totally confused. And i think that the problem in my  code, because all this 3 options returns only first row Page_Name value....Noone of manually edited rows became a part of $DataGridView1.Rows.... So this is the main problem for me...

"both the $DataGridview1 object and the main form" - both? i have only 1 $DGV. And i think i dont actuallly khow what is Main Form is...
oh i used to try set AllowUserToAddRows, but it proved useless...

Comment: @ВладимирКонстантинов Well.. the DataGridView object is added to the controls of your (main) form. When done, you should clear memory by doing `$form.Dispose()` and also ` $DataGridView1.Dispose()`. I have no idea what you called your form, so you need to use that variable name. `AllowUserToAddRows` is OK, but `AllowUserToAddRowsChange` is not a valid property, if you leave that line in, you'll see an error message.

Comment: My English is rather poor. And I often make mistakes. Sorry for this... 
I thought that DGV is the main form to display data. If i understand you correctly, i have to use 2 DGV? 1 for display exported data from csv anf the second to manually addition? 

If you rather interested there is full code file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S5jvk6YyWccRkjW1VYxMDQ_rhxzOXtuf/view?usp=sharing. i would be more than happinessFULLY if you help me.

Im honestly trying to find on docs.ms detailed instrucrion for DGV object/control. But all manuals coded at c# &.net. Its seems like chineese for me...

Comment: @ВладимирКонстантинов You need not worry about your English, because it is fine. I have edited my answer and put in demo code to show what I mean. Of course, this does not have the fancy buttons and stuff your code has, but for demo it should suffice. I hope it explains things for you.

Comment: Oh)) You r amazing!)) Thank you very very much !!Im starting to learn right now))

PS:The most part of the fancy things In my code appeared only cause i had to do anything(no matter what it would be) working after a several hours unsuccsessfull trying to do usefull  working code that i really need...

Comment: I carefully  learned this demo, and want  to thank you for your time taken!!!!)))) But my case has a little difference.... After DGV  displays csv-file content(actually 1row). I(or other user) manually  adding the next rows by  edition newrow cells.Of course whatever i do this manually added rows not becaming the part of RowCollection. So all manipulations with DGV  - elements variables taking effect only for those rows that was convert from csv content. i evev try to export  @($DataGridView1.Rows.Cells.Value)after manually adding rows  to the same csv from which 1row was exported to

Comment: "refresh" row collection. It seems like it doesnt make any sense. Csv becamed empty after thees manipulation.I started to learn documentation for bounded source for DGV. But  in all examples that i founded for data source using sql.I really think tha tsql database source for max 5 WebPages Names isnot rather good idea...